# Why do my invoices have HastedInvoiceUrl being null in Stripe?

Tags: c#, url, stripe-payments, invoice

Why do my invoices have HastedInvoiceUrl being null in Stripe? Should I configure it somehow in the backoffice of my Stripe account?

I am using the `Stripe.InvoiceService.ListAutoPagingAsync` method from C#.

My invoices have a status of draft. According to [the documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object#invoice_object-hosted_invoice_url):

> hosted_invoice_url string

> The URL for the hosted invoice page, which allows customers to view and pay an invoice. If the invoice has not been finalized yet, this will be null.

So, I would expected to see a link inside the `hosted_invoice_url` field, but it is not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior. An Invoice begins in a `draft` state, it can later be finalized at which point its status becomes `open`[1]. If you wait until your Invoice finalizes with auto-advancement[2] or manually finalize[3] the invoice yourself, the `hosted_invoice_url` field will no longer be null.

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/invoicing/overview#invoice-lifecycle

[2] https://stripe.com/docs/invoicing/integration/automatic-advancement-collection

[3] https://stripe.com/docs/invoicing/integration/workflow-transitions#finalized